# listview dynamic buttons

Tags: android, listview, button, dynamic, broadcastreceiver

i'm developing android messaging application using java when a receive a message i inserted the information of it to a database..
i want to create a listview with dynamic buttons, each button contain the data in the row of the database and i need to connect the id of the button to the id of the record so i can apply changes to the buttons such as deleting it using the id of it, and i need to create a new button every time i receive a message.
I've been searching for some answers but i didn't find anything like this..
thanks in advance.

Comment: Well dynamically adding parts to the UI is np. All xml tags have a corresponding java method. Have you tried some of that?

Comment: thanks for replaying, but i dont want to use XML in my app. i want to do it programmatic using java any suggestions..

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: @Hemsi yes, my suggestion is that you use the corresponding java methods. Create the buttons and add them to your layout (which I hope you have, as an xml). And as mentioned, all static content should be in xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- " i want to create a listview with dynamic buttons, each button contain the data in the row of the database "

Your button doesn't really need to be dynamic, you can load a `<Button>` from an XML layout which describes your `ListView` row.  Then, in your `ListView` adapters `getView() method`, use `Button.setTag()` to put a tag object on the button, set a title on the button, etc ... this tag object could simply reference your database `row _ID`.

- " and i need to connect the id of the button to the id of the record so i can apply changes to the buttons such as deleting it using the id of it "

Use `Button.getTag()` in the button `onClick()` handler to read the `_ID` and do what you need.

- " and i need to create a new button every time i receive a message."

Use a `DataSetObserver` on your adapter.  Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter when you receive this message to force the `ListView` to update itself.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer i'll work on it right now and give you my feedback.